# Woocommerce Redirect to custom page depending on order status

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to redirect users to custom order-thank you pages depending on order status?

```
Order Complete -> /standard-order-received-page/
Order Processing -> /custom-redirect-page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope help:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'func_redirectcustom');

function func_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'https://yoursite.com/custom-url';

    if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {

         wp_redirect( $url );
         exit;
    }
    // etc
}
```

Comment: To what page will this script redirect if order is failed?

Comment: @ex501 No, if order status not failed.

Comment: I wish to redirect to two pages depending on order status. If order is complete - redirect to default page.

If order is processing - redirect to custom page. Could you help with this please ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately it still redirects to standard thank you page instead of custom one when order status is processing :(

Comment: Check the order status May be Just "processing"  I am not sure.

Comment: I have edited my answer again and I check this code work fine.